# Deploying web applications with VS2010's devenv.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, bamboo, devenv

I'm attempting to use the VS2010 command line utility, devenv.exe, to deploy a web solution, eventually on a bamboo CI server. The problem is, when I use the /deploy parameter, the solution builds, but does not deploy.

I've tried different parameter sets. I've included the /project setting to deploy a single web project, and tried it without. I've tried different configuration names (debug, release) to no avail.

I'd appreciate any help I can get on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The command line utility aspnet_compiler can be used to deploy a web application. Apparently, it's what the IDE calls when you trigger a web deployment.